# Panda dataframe element comparisson against a list of values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pd dataframe with a column of 15000 values. I have another text file (so array or dataframe) with 400 values. My task is to check how many values out of those 400 are bigger than the element of the column in my data frame.

I.e. I need as an output a column len=15000 with values 0-400.

Any nice way to do this? For-looping defeats the purpose of using dataframes ;/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `'col'` as the column header and `arr400` as the array of `400` elements, one approach would be to use [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
(df.col.values[:,None] < arr400).sum(axis=1)
```

Possibly faster would be use `np.count_nonzero` -

```
np.count_nonzero(df.col.values[:,None] < arr400, axis=1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [246]: df
Out[246]: 
   col
0    7
1    2
2    6
3    0
4    8
5    1
6    6
7    3
8    1
9    1

In [247]: arr400
Out[247]: array([2, 2, 8, 7])

In [248]: (df.col.values[:,None] < arr400).sum(axis=1)
Out[248]: array([1, 2, 2, 4, 0, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4])

In [249]: np.count_nonzero(df.col.values[:,None] < arr400, axis=1)
Out[249]: array([1, 2, 2, 4, 0, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4])
```

Comment: @GedasSarpis Glad to finally get the feedback! :)